# How do I return a line of text in this way in C++?

Tags: c++, string, oop

In my code, I am tasked with making the basic framework for a game.

```
Item::Item(string itemName, int cost) {
    name = itemName;
    value = cost;
}
```

Every item pulls from the above constructor a name and a value, and the toString function below is supposed to return a string in the format of, if it were in cout, something along the lines of

```
cout << name << "(" << value << ") gold";
```

```
string Item::toString() {

}
```

The problem is, I have no idea how to return something like that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [`std::ostringstream`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostringstream), eg:

```cpp
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

std::string Item::toString() {
    std::ostringstream oss;
    oss << name << "(" << value << ") gold";
    return oss.str();
}
```

Alternatively, you can use simple string concatenation, eg:

```cpp
#include <string>

std::string Item::toString() {
    return name + "(" + std::to_string(value) + ") gold";
}
```